# Out of Memory Error in OpenJDK Docker Container

Tags: java, java-8, jboss, dockerfile

I built a Docker container for my JBoss application. Container ran in AWS EKS Fargate. I found that an OutOfMemory error occurred after the application ran for several minutes. However, it would be fine if the root user is used rather than the created user.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8u342-oraclelinux8

ENV WILDFLY_VERSION 11.0.0.Final
ENV JBOSS_HOME /usr/local/jboss_api
ENV HOME /usr/local
    
RUN groupadd -r jboss && useradd -ms /bin/bash -l -r -g  jboss jboss \
    && chown jboss /usr/local
    
USER jboss
    
WORKDIR ${HOME}
COPY ./wildfly .
RUN tar -xvf wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN rm ./wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION.tar.gz
RUN mv ./wildfly-$WILDFLY_VERSION ./jboss_api \
    && mkdir ${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/configuration/properties
    
WORKDIR ${JBOSS_HOME}
COPY ./script ./bin
COPY ./properties ./standalone/configuration
COPY ./configurations/standalone.conf ./bin/standalone.conf
    
COPY ./ROOT.war ./standalone/deployments/ROOT.war
    
WORKDIR ${JBOSS_HOME}
CMD ./bin/server.sh start
```

I figured out there is a memory issue for JVM. Therefore `-Xmx2500m` is set in java config.
`-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions` and `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap` are also added by reading some reference articles but the problem still cannot be solved.

Does anyone have an idea about this?